# Footer UL won't center

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center, footer

I am trying to center my footer with some link icons, but it just won't work, it still floats to the right.

```css
.links {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.links ul li {
     display: inline-block;
}

.links ul img {
    padding: 2.5% 4%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="x"><img src="img/mail.png" alt="Email"></a></li>
     <li><a href="x"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
     <li><a href="x"> <img src="img/tumblr.png" alt="Tumblrn"></a></li>
     <li><a href="x"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a></li>
        <li><a href="x"> <img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try apply the .links CSS style properties to the actual `<ul>` rather than the parent container. The combination of fixed width and auto margin will allow it be centered on the screen. This would also allow you to style the `.links` container as necessary.

Hopefully this helps.

Thanks!

CSS

```
.links ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.links ul li {
     display: inline-block;
}

.links ul img {
    padding: 2.5% 4%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="x"><img src="img/mail.png" alt="Email"></a></li>
        <li><a href="x"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
        <li><a href="x"> <img src="img/tumblr.png" alt="Tumblrn"></a></li>
        <li><a href="x"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a></li>
        <li><a href="x"> <img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but when I add "text-align: center;" it will float like a tiny bit too much to the right and not be completely in the middle, but works perfectly without it, thanks!

Comment: Certain browsers have default styles for `<ul>` elements that add spacing to left of the element. In Chrome this is called `-webkit-padding-start`. In Mozilla it was called `-moz-padding-start`. I'm not sure about IE or Edge. By default in Chrome it has a value of 40px. You should be able to overwrite that value for this element to 0 or whatever is necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As I can see the `div` floats left. You need to remove `float: left;` from `.links` style, and add `text-align: center` to center list items.

```css
.links {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.links ul li {
     display: inline-block;
}

.links ul img {
    padding: 2.5% 4%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="x"><img src="img/mail.png" alt="Email"></a></li>
     <li><a href="x"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
     <li><a href="x"> <img src="img/tumblr.png" alt="Tumblrn"></a></li>
     <li><a href="x"><img src="img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a></li>
        <li><a href="x"> <img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```